# VB.NET XML deserializes dates in wrong format

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, date

this is my first question here, be gentle :)

I'm trying to read a XML file into my application. The XML file follows [GS1 Warehousing Outbound Instruction](http://www.gs1.org/edi-xml/xml-warehousing-outbound-instruction-and-notification/3-2) standard, and contains dates that are in `[-]CCYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss[Z|(+|-)hh:mm]` format, which I think is some sort of XML norm?

I have generated some VB.net classes from the .xsd files provided by GS1, using xsd.exe. These classes work fine, but for some reason, it fails to parse the dates in correct format. To be specific, if the day is less than 13, it parses the date in `YYYY-DD-MM` format, resulting in incorrect dates.

I'm not sure how I should get my application to read the dates in the correct format?

```
    ' we use FTP to transfer the files
    Dim clsRequest As System.Net.FtpWebRequest =
            DirectCast(System.Net.WebRequest.Create(EndpointRoot & RecvFolder & "/" & filename), System.Net.FtpWebRequest)
    clsRequest.Method = Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile
    clsRequest.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(FtpUsername, FtpPassword)

    ' variable declaration and other stuff

    ' this happens in a try-catch block
    resp = clsRequest.GetResponse()
    respstream = resp.GetResponseStream()
    reader = New IO.StreamReader(respstream)

    Dim ser As New Serialization.XmlSerializer(GetType(WarehousingOutboundInstructionMessageType))
    doc = ser.Deserialize(reader)
    ' Deserializes the document fine, but dates suchs as 2017-03-12 are parsed as 3rd of December, 2017
```

Our computers as in Finnish locale, but I'm not sure how that would affect, as Finnish date format is `dd.mm.yyyy`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nvm, turns out I was handling the date wrongly when saving it to database.